# C language macro code - #define with 2 '##'

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor

I recently came across this question and could not find supporting document or data in explanation. The question was asked to me and the person was not willing to share the answer.

```
#define BIT(A)       BIT_##A
#define PIN_0        0
```

"Do we get BIT_0 by using macro BIT(PIN_0)? If no make necessary corrections?"

I dont know the answer to the above question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The macro

```
#define BIT(A) BIT_##A
```

means to create a *single* token from what would otherwise be two *separate* tokens. Without using `##` (the token concatenation operator), you might be tempted to do one of:

```
#define BIT(A) BIT_A
#define BIT(A) BIT_ A
```

The problem with the first is that, because `BIT_A` is already a single token, no attempt to match the `A` to the passed argument will succeed, and you'll get the literal expansion `BIT_A` no matter *what* you've used as an argument:

```
BIT(42) -> BIT_A
```

The problem with the second is that, even though `A` is a separate token and *will* therefore be subject to replacement, the final expansion will *not* be a single token:

```
BIT(42) -> BIT_ 42
```

The `##` in your macro takes the *value* specified by `A`, and appends it to the literal `BIT_` forming one token so, for example,

```
BIT(7)    -> BIT_7
BIT(PIN0) -> BIT_PIN0, but see below if you want BIT_0
```

This is covered in `C11 6.10.3.3 The ## operator`:

> ... each instance of a ## preprocessing token in the replacement list (not from an argument) is deleted and the preceding preprocessing
>   token is concatenated with the following preprocessing token.
>
> The resulting token is available for further macro replacement.

---

Now, if you want a macro that will concatenate together `BIT_` and another *already-evaluated macro* into a single token, you have to use some trickery to get it to do the initial macro substitution *before* the concatenation.

That's because the standard states that the concatenation is performed before regular macro replacement, which is why this trickery is needed. The problem with what you have:

```
#define PIN_0  0
#define BIT(A) BIT_##A
```

is that the `##` expansion of `BIT(PIN0)` will initially result in the *single* token `BIT_PIN0`. Now, although that's subject to further macro replacement, that single token doesn't actually *have* a macro replacement, so it's left as is.

To get around this, you have to use levels of indirection to coerce the preprocessor into doing regular macro replacement before `##`:

```
#define CONCAT(x,y) x ## y
#define PIN0 0
#define BIT(A) CONCAT(BIT_,A)
```

This series of macros shown above goes through a number of stages:

```
BIT(PIN0)
-> CONCAT(BIT_,PIN0)
   -> CONCAT(BIT_,0)
      -> BIT_0
```

Comment: Awesome explanation.